# Landing page to jhipster application?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jhipster

This might be a stupid question, but...What is the wisest way to implement landing page to jhipster? At the moment there is that bootsrap well in content. New index html where is the link to jhipster index(2).html or something else? I just want to add new landing page with bootsrap carousel and some marketing sh*t. If I add carousel above of content div, it is still in every page, not just in index page.

```
<body ng-app="accApp">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <p class="browserupgrade">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->
    <div ng-show="{{ENV === 'dev'}}" class="development" ng-cloak=""></div>
    <div ui-view="navbar" ng-cloak=""></div>
    <!-- NOT WORKING HERE-->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="well" ui-view="content"></div>

        <div class="footer">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your landing page is a regular html page, instead of being part of the angularjs single page app, you could just write it on a separate html file.

There are two ways to do it :

- add the raw html page in src/main/webapp/

or

- add the page in src/main/resources/templates and use thymeleaf templating engines (included in jhipster by default).
  Don't forget to serve the page with a spring MVC controller in that case.